# Extending jQuery.fn.method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible?

**For instance:**

```
jQuery.fn.data.toNumber = function(attr) {
    return Number(this.attr("data-" + attr));
    // Where "this" mean each DOMElement.
}
```

So I can call it like:

```
var number = $(document.body).data.toNumber("value");
// Act like: Number($(document.body).attr("data-value"))
```

Comment: Be aware that jQuery doesn't actually store anything in `data-` attributes when you use `.data()`, only when reading will it use it (if it's not stored some elsewhere already).  If you go ahead with this, you'll need to call the `data()` function itself in your extension, rather than looking directly at the attribute

Comment: That's not how `this` works.

Comment: it should be `jQuery.fn.dataToNumber`, would make more sense. Anyway, `data()` method already convert to relevant type, so i'm not sure what you are looking for here. Maybe provide relevant complete example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not (reasonably*) possible *in that way*, because `this` won't refer to the jQuery instance during the call (it'll refer to the `data` function).

You might consider just doing a more standard plugin method, e.g.:

```
jQuery.fn.dataAsNumber = function(attr, value) {
    if (typeof value !== "undefined") {
        // Setter
        this.data(attr, value);
        return this;
    }

    // Getter
    return +this.data(attr);
};
```

Usage:

```
var number = $(document.body).dataAsNumber("value");
```

---

* Okay, just for completeness: It's *possible*, but not reasonably. You'd have to hack `jQuery.fn.init` to make it work. I strongly recommend not doing so.

Comment: Isn't it enough: `return this.data(attr);`?

Comment: @A.Wolff The OP wants to convert it to a number

Comment: @JamesThorpe But AFAIK, `data()` already do that  e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/dbt3wqwh/

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right, it does.  That's my something learned for today!

Comment: @A.Wolff but if I just call for `this.data(attr)` and call `.dataAsNumber` containing `"true"`, for instance, it'll returns boolean.

Comment: @A.Wolff: But that's only when initializing from `data-*` attributes. `foo.data("bar", "23")` will give you back a string if you ask for it back (which is what we want, of course).